# how do I groupby a simple string list in python

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have tried searching this and the closest thing I came was using Panda packages, however is there is a way to accomplish this simple `groupby` with only inbuilt modules

My example:

```
x = ['apples', 'cat', 'cherry' 'apples', 'cherry']
```

and when group, I want my end result to be:

```
y = ['apples', 'cat', 'cherry']
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Your expected output suggests that you want to keep the strings in their order of appearance, but your comments under the answers that don't respect the order (all the ones converting your data to a set and back to a list) suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try `list(set(x))`.

I am assuming you intend to get unique values from a list, rather than "grouping" (which usually refers to a different concept).

This first converts the list into a set, which does not allow duplicates, then converts the result back to a list.

Comment: yes, thank you, you guessed right, I'm not intending for grouping but rather for unique values. :)

Comment: @Mattey Did any answer help?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can write your own method like

```
def group_array(yourlist):
   newlist=[]
   for i in yourlist:
      if i not in newlist:
         newlist.append(i)
   return newlist
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) wrapper around your array will erase any duplicated elements:

```
x = ['apples', 'cat', 'cherry', 'apples', 'cherry']
y = list(set(x))
print(y)
```

Output:

```
['apples', 'cherry', 'cat']
```

---

If you want to keep the order of the strings *(as `set`s are unordered)*, you can use a `for` loop:

```
x = ['apples', 'cat', 'cherry', 'apples', 'cherry']
y = []

for s in x:
    if s not in y:
        y.append(s)

print(y)
```

Output:

```
['apples', 'cherry', 'cat']
```